# I have an answer but can't post it

Tags: support, specific-question, protected-posts

Yes, I realize this should have gone on meta superuser, but I'm not allowed to even ask questions there.

So, I have a a complete answer to a question here on superuser:

[Mountain Lion Switcher (Cmd+Tab) not showing all apps](https://superuser.com/questions/454292/mountain-lion-switcher-cmdtab-not-showing-all-apps)

BUT - I can't answer or even comment on it. A shame, because it was a problem that really bugged me, and finding that someone else on superuser had the same issue was helpful, and I'd like to give back, but I can't due to to lack of reputation. So what do I do?

Comment: You got a couple of upvotes, so you should be able to post your answer now. This will probably migrated to meta.SU soon.

Comment: Thanks, answer posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the question was protected. Protected questions bar anyone under 10 rep (earned from posts on the site) from being able to post answers.

Questions often get protected because they usually net "me too!" and "damn I had the same problem, can anyone light a bulb up in here?" answers which aren't.

Protection has been removed from this question.